# Is an olive tree frost resistant?

Tags: trees, frost, olive

Is an olive tree frost resistant? I have a small olive tree planted in a flower pot.

There are small flies that put their larvae into the soil. Usually they are gone when the flower is outside for several days, but it's currently getting colder every night.

Comment: They're not closely related at all (they're both eudicots), but Russian Olive trees can take quite cold weather. That's probably not what you wanted to know, though. :) If your tree is in a container, I imagine it won't be able to take as cold of temperatures as it could in the ground, with deep roots, unless it's sheltered. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Olive trees prefer hot weather, but may stay outdoors as long as the temperature doesn't [dip below 14F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive_tree#Growth_and_propagation).

I plan on getting an Arbequina olive tree and I know those are fairly frost resistant.

Comment: Just for clarification: 14˚F is -10˚C

Answer (score 9):

Yes, most olive trees are frost resistant, but do not like it to get too low. Usually the most cold-tolerant varieties can take temperatures of down to 15-20 degrees Fahrenheit. If it gets colder than that in your area, or stays cold for extended periods, try moving it indoors to a sunny window during the worst parts. But once it's used to indoor temperatures, it can be damaged more easily by sudden placement in a cold environment. Try not to water too much during cold periods because the plant slows down and can't handle as much; too much water can cause root rot.

On the flies, I'm not entirely sure what they are, without a picture, but if you put a layer of dry material (such as pencil shavings or shredded paper) on top, it will discourage the laying of eggs.

Comment: It is planted in a tub and it's outside period is just to eliminate the larvae.

Comment: The flies might be fungus gnats. There's probably less fungus for them when the plants are outside. @PVitt

Answer (score 1):

We have had an olive tree in a pot in the north east of the UK for 7 years and it has grown from a small specimen to a proper tree. We have had very cold winters with regular night temperatures of -5 degrees Celsius and colder and it has survived. We have never used bubble wrap, fleece or winter mulch. Last winter it wasn’t that cold, but it nearly died. I believe that it is resistant to frost as long the soil is not to wet. If the soil is wet, even little frost can do a lot of harm.

I suggest to put the tree under a roof or even better a greenhouse. Water sparingly during the winter.

I admit that I have not looked for evidence. It’s just gardener’s observation.